MCP73871 and TPS61090 Troubleshooting
I apologize in advance if I violate any forum conventions here. If that happens I will adapt postings accordingly moving forward.
Context:
I have been working on a PCB design that incorporates the TPS61090 and MCP73871 of Adafruit's Powerboost1000C.
I've checked the Powerboost1000C circuit diagrams and Eagle PCB board files provided by Adafruit, and pretty meticulously matched everything to spec. However, when I plug this in the boost converter chip (TPS61090) gets extremely hot, and yes, eventually starts smoking.
Circuit:
For power, I will be switching between a +5V USB and a 3.7V-4.2V Lipo battery supply. The power circuit is the portion highlighted in Yellow, where the microUSB port feeds USB power from the Teensy's VUSB pin (#1) to a MCP73871 charge controller (U2, #2). Directly below this are two terminals (Orange) where the battery joins the circuit. Both power sources then feed into the TPS61090RSAR boost converter (U1, #3). If the battery is discharging, the 3.7V-4.2V will be stepped up to +5V here. Finally, power is delivered back into the Teensy through the +5V "VIN" pin (#4).



Here are the Gerber/Drill files that were used to have this board fabricated.
2 Questions:
Having read elsewhere that the passives (Capacitors, resistors, etc.) might need to be placed closer to their respective ICs, I have two questions:

Could I be missing decoupling capacitors; 10 or 100nF caps, placed close to all power inputs?

I'm thinking a board revision is the best plan of action moving forward. Are there any steps that I might want to take before that?



Very nice! But... You are too optimistic about doing something this complex and expecting it to work. You might do 1,000 boards and it still not work. Like an onion (or a pearl), get the smallest part working, and keep adding only one part at a time, testing well at each increment. Good luck.

Also, please ask a more focused (smaller) question. What this means is to follow the "incremental" methodology I just described, and ask us to help you with just one step -- not a completely untested design.

Thank you @MicroservicesOnDDD for your response, and I see what you mean about being overly optimistic (This IS quite a large project). Prior to this design I did make a standalone lipo-charging board using the MCP73831T-2ACI/OT, but it is seeming another intermediary project may be in order.
I hear you about the onion approach. Breaking things down into the smallest functional pieces has served me well so far, but maybe I overlooked that when it comes to this design.

Can you share what debugging steps you have taken so far and what the result of each investigation has been?

Your inductor may be too small (or current too high) and may be saturating. Also,.you may have layout problems. Suggest reading the TPS61090 datasheet again, and making sure of your calculations, especially for inductor current and size. And the layout section.
